# Show $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a^n b^k}{n! k!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a^{n-k} b^k}{(n-k)!k!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Show that:

\begin{align*}
  \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a^n b^k}{n! k!} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{a^{n-k} b^k}{(n-k)!k!} \\
\end{align*}

Would the substitution $m=n+k$ modify the left hand side to the right hand side? Could someone explain this? Thank you.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the comment we calculate the *[Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product)* of series. We assume absolute convergence of the series
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n!}\qquad\mathrm{and}\qquad
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{b_k}{k!}
\end{align*}
so that the manipulation of the series is admissible.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}}\color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{a^nb^k}{n!k!}}
> &=\sum_{q=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{{n+k=q}\atop{n,k\geq 0}}\frac{a^nb^k}{n!k!}\right)\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{q=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^q\frac{a^{q-k}b^k}{(q-k)!k!}\right)\tag{2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{a^{n-k}b^k}{(n-k)!k!}}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we collect summands according to increasing $q=n+k, n,k\geq 0$.
- In (2) we eliminate $n$ using $n+k=q$.
- In (3) we rename $q$ to $n$ and omit the parentheses.